# Use ntfsundelete on dd image

Tags: linux, ntfs, dd

I have a feeling the answer to this is right in front of me, but I am not seeing it. :/

I used `dd` to to create an image of a failing drive. Now, I would like to attempt to recover anything I can from an NTFS partition on the drive using `ntfsundelete`

The problem is that I don't understand how to specify the NTFS partition(mounted or not) as input for `ntfsundelete`.

I have mounted the NTFS partition(specified the block offset) on a loopback, `/mnt/myhdd`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manpage for ntfsundelete says it works on devices, not mounted filesystems.  You would need unmount /mnt/myhdd and run ntfsundelete on `/dev/loop0`, or whichever loop device you set up.

Obviously you want `-u`.  It might be that you need to specify `-m` as well in order to get anything to happen.  E.g. `-m <filename>`.  After running `-s` previously to look for available filenames.  `-m *` to undelete all available files might be necessary if you have a lot, but that might be a bit painful.

Comment: @Jonathan remembering to unmount the filesystem first!

Comment: Ahhh... Will try this as soon as I get back to my computer and report back.

Comment: Sorry, I never made it back here to accept this answer. I ended up getting it to work because of your answer. Thanks for the help! Hope you had a nice year. ;)